# Bug? Windows phone 8 Resource Intensive Task on release mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task, background-agents, background-agent

My application is using the Auto-upload feature which allows using a Resource Intensive Task to upload pictures.

If I use ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest then it works fine, but when I erase this line of code, the resource intensive task never executes (and I see that the phone meets all the requirements).

The app is in release mode btw.

What could happen? It will be executed in several hours after or it will never be executed? Is there any bug?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the task stops launching after you remove `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest`...

Did you just remove that line, or did you replace it with `ScheduledActionService.Add`?  You still have to add your task to the scheduler.

EDIT

I'd never encountered this personally, but per another SO question ([Any Tips for getting Windows Phone 8 Resource Intensive Task to Run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664796/any-tips-for-getting-windows-phone-8-resource-intensive-task-to-run)), there is a known bug in the pre-GDR2 versions of Windows Phone 8 in which Resource-Intensive Tasks simply don't run in Release builds.  Ouch.

So if your device hasn't had the GDR2 update... not much to be done, it seems!

Comment: No no, what I say is that if I put the LaunchForTest, the Resource Intensive Task works, but if I REMOVE the LaunchForTest it doesn't seem to work, I wait a lot of time but this task doesn't run.

Comment: Right, I hear that.  Now that `LaunchForTest` is gone, how are you informing the OS that there's a task to run?

Comment: Well, I call ScheduledActionService.Add, what else should I do? BTW. If an App use Resource Intensive Task (not Scheduled), when you go to config and see the "background tasks" option, the name of the app appears there?

Comment: That's dependent on your mobile carrier, unfortunately.  If they haven't yet rolled it out, consider it unlikely - it's been out for some time.  You may already have it - check your phone's system info.  I don't know precisely what to look for, but google should help.

Comment: I think that the fault is in my manifest. Supossing that the project is called "My Project" and the name of the Task Agent is "My Agent", how should I fill the manifest with this?                                  <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
        <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="MyAgent" Source="MyAgent" Type="MyAgent.ScheduledAgent" />
      </ExtendedTask>